# What does "Ride much?" mean in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

From [the movie Unleashed](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0342258/):

A woman is on the bike with her pets and many stuffs. So, she sort of blocks a way and stumbles.
When a stranger guy passes by her, he says to her "ride much?".
He is also on the bike.

First, I understand 'ride much' means 'are you okay?'. I don't fully understand what 'ride much' means.

Comment: It's not very clear, but I assume he means "Do you ride [a bicycle] much?", implying that she doesn't look like an experienced cyclist.

Comment: This is a good question and I can understand why it would be asked. Sometimes, the shortening of a full sentence is hard to understand!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is an abbreviated form of:

> Do you ride much?

Or more elaborately:

> Do you often ride a bicycle?

From the context you've given, it's likely that the question is being asked *sarcastically* - the speaker is hinting that the answer might be "no", because she is riding in a way that suggests a lack of experience.

Comment: Thank your for your kind answer. Didn't assume that it would be an abbreviation!

Comment: I think it should be made clear that this construction ("X much?") is _rude_. The stranger is irritated that his path was blocked.

Comment: @AlexReinking - Rude? Maybe sarcastic. Or even poking fun at a friend thats having difficulty. But not rude.

Comment: @StingyJack Sarcasm is often rude and just a thin disguise for mockery, which I'd say fits this case.